# Can not update web reference in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, acumatica

My project in Visual studio 2013 consumes Acumatica web service APIs on another server. I had no problem with adding web reference and calling Acumatica web service API in my code, until recently I added new API into the web service in Acumatica, and then tried to update web service reference in my project. I  right clicked on "web service" in Visual studio and then click on "update web reference" to update, however, I was still getting the old APIs, even though I used exactly same URL. I put the URL in browser and I could see the new APIs but when I tried to update, I just couldn't get them into Visual Studio.

When I put that URL into browser to view the WSDL XML, I noticed I only got new APIs after I logged into Acumatica and I was getting old APIs before I logged in. It seems Acumatica only sends updated WSDL xml after users log in, which causes problem to Visual Studio, since there is no way to log in first in Visual studio.

Actually I had successfully updated my web reference before, but almost every time I tried to update reference, I got this problem, then after keeping trying  many times, the reference eventually got updated...but this time, the problem seems to just hang on there and doesn't go...

By the way, I tried to go to command line to use wsdl.exe to generate reference class but still got old APIs.

I just don't understand why Acumatica requires logging in to give out new APIs...

If anybody could give me any clue to solve this problem, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: How do you "login"? You could download the WSDL file after logging-in (with your desktop web-browser) and then pass that into `wsdl.exe`, otherwise this sounds like an issue with Acumatica, nothing we can help you with.

Comment: @Dai, that 's a great idea! I will tried it.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks again, @Dai. I don't know why I didn't realize this simple solution...;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Converting my solution from a comment to an answer)

I believe the Visual Studio GUI frontend for `wsdl.exe` does allow you to perform a login action (by showing a WebBrowser control) prior to downloading the `.wsdl` file, but in the event that doesn't work you can always manually download the `.wsdl` via your desktop browser and then invoke `wsdl.exe` from the command-line, providing the downloaded file as a command-line argument.